# Is there any way of writing a command to interrupt time.sleep for a discord music bot?

Tags: python, discord, replit

I am trying to code a music bot to play music in a discord server. The issue I am having is with the "play" command I am using, when a song is playing from this version of the play command, no other commands (e.g. ".disconnect") work. The code I have written for this is

```
@bot.command()
async def play(ctx,search):
  query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode({'search_query': search})
  htm_content = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.youtube.com/results?'+query_string)
  search_results = re.findall(r'/watch\?v=(.{11})',htm_content.read().decode())
  URL = ('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+search_results[0])
  song_queue.append(URL)
  if len(song_queue)>1:
    await ctx.channel.send("Song queued.")

  for index in range(len(song_queue)):
    yt = YouTube(song_queue[index])
    video_length = yt.length
    await play_song(ctx, song_queue[index])
    await ctx.channel.send(song_queue[index])
    del song_queue[0]
    time.sleep(video_length)
```

I am assuming that the issue comes from the `time.sleep(video_length)` pausing all of the code and not just pausing the for loop that it's in.

Comment: Yes, this is why `time.sleep` is not a very good tool for most jobs. It causes the entire thread to sleep. You'd be better off looking into scheduling functions to run in the future instead of using `sleep`.

Answer (score 0):

you could also have a function that while the video is plaing it repeats a function
ex

```
def musicpause():
      while videoplay is true
          time.sleep(.1)
```

or

```
def musicpause(): 
      if videotime > 0
         time.sleep(.1)
```

hope this helps